# How to write sql query in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a raw sql query which i run using yii2 `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()` but then i wonder i how i can use yii's method of writing queries to actualize the same thing.

```
 $m = "SELECT p.basic_plan_amt AS basic,p.premium_plan_amt AS premium,p.daju_plan_amt AS daju,c.name 
 AS country FROM price p LEFT JOIN country c ON p.country_id = c.id WHERE p.country_id = " .$country_id;
```

though the above query works well and provide expected result, but then how can i write the same query using the below format

```
$model = \backend\models\Price::find()->select([p.basic_plan_amt AS basic,p.premium_plan_amt AS 
premium,p.daju_plan_amt AS daju,c.name 
AS country])->where(['country_id' => $country_id])->all();
```

Comment: Is your question is about "is it possible to use methods to create sql requests" ? If so have you checked the yii documentation : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder

Comment: @Lucas Gras  I know it's possible but then i don't know how to achieve this, that's my question, need someone to put me through. Thanks

Comment: You mean how to write `join()` in ActiveRecord?

Comment: @Insane Skull yes how to use alias on table and column and also write join statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are the examples of query in yii hope it will help you [More reference](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-joins/#RelationModel)

**Relation Model**

```
$model = User::find()
        ->with('comments')
        ->all();
foreach ($model as $user) {
    // get data from relation model
    $comments = $user->comments;
        ......
    foreach($comments as $comment){
        ........
    }
}
```

**joinWith()
Sample 1:**

```
$model = User::find()
        ->joinWith('comments')
        ->all();
```

**Sample 2:**

```
$model = User::find()
        ->joinWith('comments')
        ->orderBy('tbl_comments_id.id, tbl_user.id')
        ->all();
```

**innerJoinWith()**

```
$model = User::find()
        ->innerJoinWith('comments', false)
        ->all();
// equivalent to the above
$model = User::find()
        ->joinWith('comments', false, 'INNER JOIN')
        ->all();
```

**Join()**

```
JOIN_TYPE = INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN etc
Syntax


$query = new Query;
$query  ->select(['SELECT COLUMNS'])  
        ->from('TABLE_NAME_1')
        ->join( 'JOIN_TYPE', 
            'TABLE_NAME_2',
            'TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN =TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN'
        ); 
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

**Sample 1:**

```
$query = new Query;
$query  ->select([
        'tbl_user.username AS name', 
        'tbl_category.categoryname as  Category',
        'tbl_document.documentname']
        )  
        ->from('tbl_user')
        ->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'tbl_category',
            'tbl_category.createdby =tbl_user.userid')      
        ->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'tbl_document', 
            'tbl_category.cid =tbl_document.did')
        ->LIMIT(5)  ; 

$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

**Output Query**

```
SELECT `tbl_user`.`username` AS `name`, `tbl_category`.`categoryname` AS `Category` 
FROM `tbl_user` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_category` ON tbl_category.createdby =tbl_user.userid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_document` ON tbl_category.cid =tbl_document.did 
LIMIT 5
```

**leftJoin()
Sample 1:**

```
$query = new Query;
$query  ->select(['tbl_user.username AS name', 'tbl_category.type as Category'])  
        ->from('tbl_user')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_category', 'tbl_category.createdby = tbl_user.userid')
        ->limit(2); 

$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

**Output Query**

```
SELECT `tbl_user`.`username` AS `name`, `tbl_category`.`type` AS `Category`
FROM `tbl_user` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_category` ON tbl_category.createdby = tbl_user.useridd 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

use `createcommand()` method:

```
use yii\db\Query(); 
$connection = \Yii::$app->db; 
$query = new Query; 
$insql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT* FROM inventory );  
$result=$insql->queryAll();
```

the above method list all data from the inventory table.